# How to get subView's data in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I have many subviews (button,label,textField)inside view.These are dynamically created depending on the `xml` elements. if `xml` elements are 13, the total button will also be 13 buttons.  i know how to search all subviews inside view and which subviews is `UIButton` or `UITextField` by the following code.

```
for subView in view.subviews {

if subView is UILabel {

}
else if subView is UITextField {

}

}
```

what i want to know is how can i get the button's tag and title and textField's text?

Comment: Please share screenshot for better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for subView in view.subviews {

            if subView is UILabel {
                let label = subView as! UILabel
                let labelText = label.text

            }
            else if subView is UITextField {
                let textField = subView as! UITextField
                let textFieldText = textField.text
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this :

```
for subView in self.view.subviews
{
    if let textField = subView as? UITextField
    {
         let textFieldText = textField.text
         print(textFieldText!)
    } 
    else if let Label = subView as? UILabel
    {
        let labelText = Label.text
        print(labelText!)
    }
}
```